# Setting Default Value of ComboBox (Dropdown) when bound to an Access Database (VB.Net)

Tags: vb.net, .net-4.0, combobox

So what i'm looking to do is this. I currently have a ComboBox that displays a list of usernames. When the form loads, this comboBox is a drop down and an analyst can select their name from the list. What i'm looking to do is have the default value of the combobox show "Select Username" then of course when they select the drop down box that's not displayed.

I could essentially just add that as a value in the access database, but where's the fun in that. SO yea, code time:

```
Private Sub FillCombo()

    Dim fillcon As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=Server Location.accdb")
    Dim query As String = ("SELECT User_Name, User_ID FROM Analysts")
    Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(query, fillcon)
    Dim ds As New DataSet


    da.Fill(ds)
    ComboBox1.ValueMember = "User_Name"
    ComboBox1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
    ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0
    ComboBox1.SelectedItem = "Select UserID"


    TextBox10.DataBindings.Clear()
    TextBox10.DataBindings.Add("Text", ds.Tables(0), "User_ID")


End Sub
```

Now FillCombo() is placed in Form Load and works beautifully, the only thing that doesn't work...is "Select UserID" is not shown as the default text. Ideas?

Comment: I think you can just set the Text property for that.  `ComboBox1.Text = "Select UserID"`.  do that when you reset the form, the text should disappear when it drops down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not bind the combobox to the data source. Use this method to populate your combobox. You will then be able to set the text property.

```
   da.Fill(ds)

   for each dr as datarow in ds.Tables(0).Rows   
        ComboBox1.Items.Add(dr("User_Name"))
   next 

  ComboBox1.Text = "Select UserID"
```

Comment: Boom...that did it and I actually learned something new. Thanks Gary, wish i could mail you one of my homebrews mate.

Answer (score 1):

You can't add items to a databound combobox, and you don't have to add it to the database, just add it to the datatable

```
Dim row = ds.Tables(0).NewRow()
row(0) = "Select UserID"
row(1) = 0
ds.Tables(0).Rows.InsertAt(row, 0)
ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0
```

Comment: So i tried that, and the database just doesn't load as the box is populated with nothing.
 Dim row = ds.Tables(0).NewRow()

        da.Fill(ds)
        ComboBox1.ValueMember = "User_Name"
        ComboBox1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
        row(0) = "Select UserID"
        ds.Tables(0).Rows.InsertAt(row, 0)
        ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0

Answer (score 0):

do not set the selecteditem property, that item is not in the list.
set the text property to the text you want

```
ComboBox1.Text = "Select UserID"
```

Comment: So I changed it to   
   da.Fill(ds)
        ComboBox1.ValueMember = "User_Name"
        ComboBox1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
        ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0
        ComboBox1.Text = "Select UserID"

But what's happening is the very first value from the access database is still showing.

Comment: oh, my bad. You are using a bound combobox, we never bind our controls here. I believe for bound controls the item must be in the list.

Comment: So let me ask this, If i was to make a label and change the Auto-Size to False and put it over the combobox text field. Any idea on how to make that label disappear when clicking on the ComboBox? I've tried the ComboBox1_Click and through in LabelXYZ.visible = False, of course that didn't work.